# Is it safe to clear observers from the Subject object in rxjs in this scenario?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

This seems to work and I am curious to know if this is safe. Take the following scenario...

In a shared service class I have:

```
this.subject = new Rx.Subject();
```

Lets say this observable has multiple subscribers.

The subject looks like so `subject.observers = [Subscriber 1, Subscriber 2...Subscriber n]`

If I wanted the `Subject` to stop notifying all subscribers, I know I can do `subject.unsubscribe()` and that will set `subject.observers = null`, but this then does not allow any future subscribers to attach to the `this.subject` instance.

Okay heres the question...

Instead of using `subject.unsubscribe()`, can I just clear out the observers array like so `subject.observers.length = 0` with out causing any issues?

This then clears out all of the subscribers it was watching but still allows me to attach other subscribers in the future.

I can iterate through the `subject.observers` array and unsubscribe that way, but if I just clear out the observers array with out causing any memory leaks, I'd prefer the way.

Comment: What's wrong with iterating `subject.observers` and unsubscribing each one of them?

Comment: definitely nothing wrong it, the question is more... "this seems to work, but are there any issues caused to the library by doing it this way? Or is everything okay?"

Comment: Unsubscribing using `unsubscribe()` is a legitimate way of unsubscribing so you don't need to worry about it. Actually an Observable is obligated to return subscription that is able unsubscribe from its Observable (usually using a callback function).

Comment: Generally you should not mess with internal APIs, I guess. Resetting the observers array could potentially be harmful - even if it is not harmful today it might be at some point in future releases. You should really use the standard approach here by unsubscribing all subscribers. Just use `subject.observers.forEach(obs => obs.unsubscribe())`. I see no reason not to follow best practices here.

Comment: @chromate thanks for the advice, ill play it safe